# How to keep only digits in a string for a column of a Data Frame?

Tags: python, sorting, filter

I have seen posts for how to do this with a single string. But how could I do this for every cell of a column in a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace every non-digit symbol for every cell in all columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "column_1": ["col_1_row_1", "col_1_row_2"],
    "column_2": ["col_2_row_1", "col_2_row_2"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df.replace(r"\D+", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

result

```
      column_1     column_2
0  col_1_row_1  col_2_row_1
1  col_1_row_2  col_2_row_2

  column_1 column_2
0       11       21
1       12       22
```

If you want to replace every non-digit symbol for every cell in certain column:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "column_1": ["col_1_row_1", "col_1_row_2"],
    "column_2": ["col_2_row_1", "col_2_row_2"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df["column_1"].replace(r"\D+", "", regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

result

```
      column_1     column_2
0  col_1_row_1  col_2_row_1
1  col_1_row_2  col_2_row_2

  column_1     column_2
0       11  col_2_row_1
1       12  col_2_row_2
```

Comment: Fantastic answer Sir, I applaud you and accept your answer for my question. Thank you @Etoneja, this works for my application and is much better than using many .replace on my columns.